# C# REGEX. Почему не находятся специальные символы?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Использую простую конструкцию

```
string text = "текст который отлично находится если убрать «» знаки";
string pattern = $"\b{text}\b";
var match = Regex.Match(text, pattern);
```

Если убрать `«»` из текста - то находится, а с ними же не нет. Можно ли как то это пофиксить?

Иногда мне нужно находить текст вместе с ними.

Comment: Должно быть `string pattern = $@"\b{text}\b";` или `string pattern = $"\\b{text}\\b";`. Кстати, `«»` не являются специальными символами в регулярных выражениях, так что если они в середине искомой фразы, проблем с правильным использованием границы слова быть не должно.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew по прежнему не находит. Проверяю как в проекте, так и в онлайн regex тестерах

Comment: Приведите пример.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew "Фраза со словом «Пример»", "«Пример»", "Пример".
Три типа присылаемых значений. В первых двух случаях находится только по вхождению в переменную "«Пример»", а все вместе они находятся по слову "Пример". 
Надеюсь вы это имели ввиду.

Comment: Не совсем ясно. Что вы пытаетесь сделать? Хотите, чтобы при поиске `«Пример»` также находился `Пример`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew наоборот) При поиске (Пример) - находились все три варианта, а («Пример») - находил лишь только два.

Comment: Ясно, тогда вам, скорее всего, подойдёт `string pattern = $@"(?<!\w){Regex.Escape(text)}(?!\w)";`. Хотя `(?<!\w)«Пример»(?!\w)` не найдёт совпадения в строке `«Пример»123` или `Первый«Пример»`